# Building Tensorflow with LTCG

Tags: windows, tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to build Tensorflow 1.14 on Windows using VS 2017 with LTCG (link time code generation) enabled. I'm hitting this crash partway through the build:

```
external/bazel_tools/tools/def_parser/def_parser.exe bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/ops/_sparse_feature_cross_op.so.gen.def _sparse_feature_cross_op.so @bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/ops/_sparse_feature_cross_op.so.gen.def-0.params

ERROR: E:/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/layers/BUILD:22:1: DefParser tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/ops/_sparse_feature_cross_op.so.gen.def failed (Exit -1073741819): def_parser.exe failed: error executing command
```

My environment is:

- Tensorflow version: 1.14 (no source edits). Retrieved from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git, branch r1.14
- Visual Studio version: VS 2017
- Bazel version: 0.25.2

Steps:

```
set BAZEL_VC=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC
set BAZEL_VC_FULL_VERSION=14.16.27023
set BAZEL_VS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise
python .\configure.py  
<Use all of the defaults>
bazel build -s --config=opt --copt=/GL --linkopt=/LTCG //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I've tried various versions of bazel (0.21, 0.26, 0.27, 0.28) and also tried with VS 2019 while changing the BAZEL_* environment variables, but I'm still hitting the same error. I've run the `external/bazel_tools/tools/def_parser/def_parser.exe bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/ops/_sparse_feature_cross_op.so.gen.def _sparse_feature_cross_op.so @bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/ops/_sparse_feature_cross_op.so.gen.def-0.params` command locally and it does crash with the -1073741819 error code.

Has anyone had experience building Tensorflow with LTCG, or using Bazel with LTCG?

Answer (score 0):

TF 1.14 requires Bazel 0.24.1, AFAIK it doesn't work with newer Bazel versions (>= 0.25).

I don't know what the problem could be, but I can tell you how to debug it.

You'll need to get Bazel 0.24.1's sources, add debug logging to the DEF parser, build Bazel from source, and use the resulting binary to build TensorFlow.

To do so:

1. download the [Bazel 0.24.1 release](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.24.1/bazel-0.24.1-windows-x86_64.exe)
2. download and extract the [0.24.1 sources](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.24.1/bazel-0.24.1-dist.zip) **OR** git clone Bazel's GitHub tree and check out the 0.24.1 tag
3. add debug logging / printf calls to third_party/def_parser/* as you see fit
4. with the 0.24.1 release binary, run `bazel build //src:bazel.exe` in the patched source tree
5. use the resulting `bazel-bin\src\bazel.exe` to build TensorFlow
6. if you need to add more debug logging, repeat steps 3..5

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to build TF 2.2 with MSVC 2019 v142 toolset (exact version 14.25.28610) with `/GL` and `/LTCG` options and I got the same error, but in a slightly different place. Here is my cmd line:

```
set BAZEL_VC=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC

bazel build --config=opt --config=windows --compilation_mode=opt --strip=always --copt="/MT" --copt="/Oy" --copt="/fp:fast" --copt="/GL" --linkopt="/DEBUG:NONE" --linkopt="/LTCG" --linkopt="/NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib" --linkopt="/NODEFAULTLIB:vcruntime.lib" --local_ram_resources=6512 --subcommands //tensorflow/tools/lib_package:libtensorflow > out.log 2>&1
```

I had to specify the MSVC tools folder directly, because Bazel kept trying to use the older version, details in [this issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/8589#issuecomment-625706415).

This is where it fails:

```
SUBCOMMAND: # //tensorflow:tf_custom_op_library_additional_deps.dll [action 'DefParser tensorflow/tf_custom_op_library_additional_deps.dll.gen.def', configuration: e5dbf2de175ef0b99efae20c93576efaae21f61b49e23200be8ee726f25b19c6]
cd C:/users/roman.kruglov/_bazel_roman.kruglov/e5u6xdzn/execroot/org_tensorflow
  SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
    SET PYTHON_BIN_PATH=C:/Users/roman.kruglov/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe
    SET PYTHON_LIB_PATH=C:/Users/roman.kruglov/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/lib/site-packages
    SET RUNFILES_MANIFEST_ONLY=1
    SET TF2_BEHAVIOR=1
    SET TF_CONFIGURE_IOS=0
    SET TF_ENABLE_XLA=1
  external/bazel_tools/tools/def_parser/def_parser.exe bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/tensorflow/tf_custom_op_library_additional_deps.dll.gen.def tf_custom_op_library_additional_deps.dll @bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/tensorflow/tf_custom_op_library_additional_deps.dll.gen.def-0.params
ERROR: C:/data_d/git/test/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:750:1: DefParser tensorflow/tf_custom_op_library_additional_deps.dll.gen.def failed (Exit -1073741819)
```

**My conjecture** currently is - it happens because with `/GL` enabled cl.exe produces a different format of output. As specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gl-whole-program-optimization?view=vs-2019), `.obj files produced with /GL will not be available to such linker utilities as EDITBIN and DUMPBIN`. I guess this DefParser tool just can't read that output. I'll try to rebuild without Global Optimization on and share my findings.

I guess it's just not feasible.

**P.S.** Just a heads up. I tried to build with /GL and stuff numerous times with no luck. I managed to build without /GL and stuff numerous times. There are several posts in the internet with similar attempts all failing with roughly the same symptoms.

Thus I conclude that my conjecture was true and it's not possible to build TF with global optimizations or link time code generation, etc. I guess the same stands true for Linux, because using lto there changes output object files format as well.